# Purposely waste all of main memory to learn fragmentation

Tags: c, memory, heap-fragmentation

In my class we have an assignment and one of the questions states:

> Memory fragmentation in C: Design, implement, and run a C-program that does the following: it allocated memory for a sequence of of 3m arrays of size 500000 elements each; then it deallocates all even-numbered arrays and allocates a sequence of m arrays of size 700000 elements each. Measure the amounts of time your program requires for the allocations of the first sequence and for the second sequence. Choose m so that you exhaust all of the main memory available to your program. Explain your timings

My implementation of this is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>

void main(){
    clock_t begin1, stop1, begin2, stop2;
    double tdif = 0, tdif2 = 0;
    for(int k=0;k<1000;k++){
    double dif, dif2;
    const int m = 50000;
    begin1 = clock();
    printf("Step One\n");
    int *container[3*m];
    for(int i=0;i<(3*m);i++)
    {
        int *tmpAry = (int *)malloc(500000*sizeof(int));
        container[i] = tmpAry;
    }
    stop1 = clock();
    printf("Step Two\n");
    for(int i=0;i<(3*m);i+=2)
    {
    free(container[i]);
    }
    begin2 = clock();
    printf("Step Three\n");
    int *container2[m];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
    int *tmpAry = (int *)malloc(700000*sizeof(int));
    container2[i] = tmpAry;
    }
    stop2 = clock();
    dif = (stop1 - begin1)/1000.00;
    dif2 = (stop2 - begin2)/1000.00;
    tdif+=dif;
    tdif/=2;
    tdif2+=dif2;
    tdif2/=2;
}
printf("To Allocate the first array it took: %.5f\n",tdif);
printf("To Allocate the second array it took: %.5f\n",tdif2);
system("pause");
};
```

I have changed this up a few different ways, but the consistencies I see are that when I initially allocate the memory for 3*m*500000 element arrays it uses up all of the available main memory. But then when I tell it to free them the memory is not released back to the OS so then when it goes to allocate the m*700000 element arrays it does it in the page file (swap memory) so it does not actually display memory fragmentation.

The above code runs this 1000 times and averages it, it takes quite some time. The first sequence average took 2.06913 seconds and the second sequence took 0.67594 seconds. To me the second sequence is supposed to take longer to show how fragmentation works, but because of the swap being used this does not occur. Is there a way around this or am I wrong in my assumption?

I will ask the professor about what I have on monday but until then any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Choose m so that you exhaust all of the main memory available to your program" - that can actually be rather difficult on some systems. As I type, I have 2GB main memory, but a process on 32 bit Windows can only use 2GB of virtual address space anyway. If I had 3GB main memory, it would be impossible for one process to use it all. What I can't remember, though, is whether all 32 bit processes share the same 2GB and the other 1GB is only used by the OS and drivers, or whether 32 bit Windows is capable of properly sharing 3GB between processes.

Comment: Some operating systems will not assign main memory until it is actually written to, so your timings may not mean much in terms of fragmentation.  It may just be virtually fragmented.

Comment: Something else to check: depending on your OS and settings, you might be hitting the `mmap` threshold in `malloc`.  50000 elements is just under the default value of `M_MMAP_MAX`, and if you are on 32-bit Linux, the blocks are over `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD`.  If you are indeed triggering `mmap`,  instead of using the heap, the allocations end up as individual mappings, and do not suffer from fragmentation.  Try reducing the size of the blocks.

Comment: Why are you doing `#include <iostream>` in a C program?  C is not C++.

Comment: @Greg: How does `mmap` avoid fragmentation?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Every process on Win32 has it's own 2GB of virtual address space, whether that space is provided by actual RAM or virtual memory. If there's not enough physical RAM available to supply them all, virtual memory is used instead.

Comment: @KenWhite: Technically, it's all virtual. The OS can page you out whenever it wants to (but won't necessarily).

Comment: @Linuxios: Not sure what your point is; my comment was based on what Steve said about not remembering, and I addressed the comment specifically to him regarding that statement.

Comment: @KenWhite: I was talking about your last statment that the os starts suing virtual memory, I was just saying that it's actually using virtual memory the entire time. Just a little technicality. It was silly for me to bring it up.

Comment: @Linuxios: No problem. The last sentence should probably have been left out; the comment would have been fine without it. Just wasn't sure what you were criticizing. :-)

Comment: What OS are you using? On both test machines I have (one OS X.6.8 laptop, one 64-bit Linux), your code takes several *minutes* to do one iteration...

Comment: @Gabe Now that I think about it more, my point is wrong.  On Linux at least the mappings will end up contiguous, and exhibit the same fragmentation as the heap.

Comment: @Ken: the thing I can't remember can be rephrased as follows: on a 32 bit Windows OS (Windows version of your choice) with 3GB of RAM, is it possible for two processes simultaneously to have 1.1 GB of their address space mapped to RAM at the same time (when they're not sharing memory, of course)? I vaguely remember that at some time there was an issue with common BOISes or the OS or both, that meant 1GB of the RAM is usable only by the kernel and devices, it can never be made available to processes.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, it's possible. If a machine has 4GB of RAM, though, it might not be able to map it all because some might be dedicated to devices. However, in that case the kernel wouldn't be able to use it either.

Comment: @EdHeal Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100).

Answer (score 2):

Many libc implementations (I think glibc included) don't release memory back to the OS when you call `free()`, but keep it so you can use it on the next allocation without a syscall. Also, because of the complexity of modern paging and virtual memory stratagies, you can never be sure where anything is in physical memory, which makes it almost imposible to intentionally fragment it (even if it comes fragmented). You have to remember, all *virtual* memory, and all *physical* memory are different beasts.

(The following is written for Linux, but probably applicable to Windows and OSX)

When your program makes the first allocations, let's say there is enough physical memory for the OS to squeeze all of the pages in. They aren't all next to each-other in physical memory -- they are scattered wherever they can be. Then the OS modifies the page table to make a set of continuous *virtual* addresses, that refer to the scattered pages around in memory. But here's the thing -- because you don't really use the first memory you allocate, it becomes a really good candidate for swapping out. So, when you come along to do the next allocations, the OS, running out of memory, will probably swap out some of those pages to make room for the new ones. Because of this, you are actually measuring disk speeds, and the efficiency of the operations systems paging mechanism -- not fragmentation.

Remember, an set of continuous virtual addresses is almost never physically continuous in practice (or even in memory).